# Getting Text Input to another Screen using Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am creating an app with Screen Manager. 
I want to get text input from one screen click Next and then use it in a label for another screen and save the value as a global variable.

My question is: How to make it work, because it doesn't work the way I want it to. The label is always 0 and is never the value I type in. The value of the global variable never changes.

main.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

global var
var = 0


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    global var

    def SaveResult(self, text):
        global var
        g = int(text)
        return var


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    global var
    a = NumericProperty('')
    a = str(var)
```

and my test.kv

```
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    FirstScreen:
        id: screen1
        name: "FirstScreen"
        manager: screen_manager
    SecondScreen:
        id: screen2
        name: "SecondScreen"
        manager: screen_manager


<FirstScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1
            Rectangle:
                # self here refers to the widget i.e BoxLayout
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        TextInput:
            id: text_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint_x: .4
            size_hint_y: .1
            pos_hint: {'x': .1, 'y': .20}
        Button:
            background_color: 0.2, 0.7, 1, 1,
            font_size: root.width / 15
            id: btn1
            text: "Next"
            on_press:
                root.SaveResult(text_input.text)
                root.manager.current = 'SecondScreen'
            size_hint_x: .4
            size_hint_y: .1
            pos_hint: {'x': .5, 'y': .20}
<SecondScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1
            Rectangle:
                # self here refers to the widget i.e BoxLayout
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Label:
            color: 0.2, 0.7, 1, 1,
            font_size: root.width / 15
            id: lb1
            text: root.a
            size_hint_x: .4
            size_hint_y: .2
            pos_hint: {'x': .3, 'y': .8}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How to make it work, because it doesn't work the way I want it to. The label is always 0 and is never the value I type in. The value of the global variable never changes.